# Mostrar un texto dependiendo de la validación del campo del formulario

Tags: html, css

Estoy buscando la forma de validar un `<input>` que a medida que voy escribiendo en él me valide la longitud de los caracteres sin tener que pulsar un botón.

Tengo el código hecho, en HTML/CSS, y el problema es que siempre me lo pone por defecto en rojo y la idea es que mientras voy escribiendo coloque por debajo del `<input>` vaya colocando un mensaje de alerta como los siguientes:

[image: Mensaje para un IBAN inválido]

Y que cuando llegue a la longitud esté así:

[image: Mensaje para un IBAN válido]

Éste es mi código:

```css
/* Import Google font - Poppins */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.input-field label{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

.input-field input{
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.input-field input:valid,
.input-field input:invalid{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.input-field input:invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.input-field input:is(:focus, :valid){
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

.input-field input[type="date"]{
  color: #707070;
}

.input-field input[type="date"]:valid{
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-field">
      <label>Iban</label>
      <input id="iban" name="iban" pattern="[A-Za-z]{24}" required></input>
    <span class="status"></span>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Tiene el js?, si lo tienes agrégalo a la pregunta

Comment: tenes una expresion regular ahi en el input, cuando pones una cadena con a-z/A-Z de 24 caracteres entonces se pone en verde pero si pones 25 ya vuelve al rojo. Como queres validar el input exactamente?

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux , el código que está usando no necesita JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es tan sencilla como usar el operador CSS [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) para indicar el siguiente elemento hermano adyacentes y [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::before) o [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after) para introducir el texto que desees dentro del elemento (antes o después del contenido real que tenga):

```
.input-field input:valid + .status::before {
  color: green;
  content: 'El IBAN es correcto';
}

.input-field input:invalid + .status::before {
  color: red;
  content: 'El IBAN es incorrecto';
}
```

El primer selector está buscando el siguiente hermano con clase `status` del campo del formulario válido. Le asigna el texto "El IBAN es correcto" y un color verde.

El segundo selector está buscando el siguiente hermano con clase `status` del campo del formulario inválido. Le asigna el texto "El IBAN es incorrecto" y un color de texto rojo.

Ejemplo agregando los estilos a tu código:

```css
/* Import Google font - Poppins */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.input-field label{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

.input-field input{
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 42px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 8px 0;
  /* Un par de mejoras visuales */
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.input-field input:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.input-field input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Texto para el campo válido */
.input-field input:valid + .status::before {
  color: green;
  content: '✔ El IBAN es correcto';
}

/* Texto para el campo incorrecto */
.input-field input:invalid + .status::before {
  color: red;
  content: '✘ El IBAN es incorrecto';
}

.input-field input:is(:focus, :valid){
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

.input-field input[type="date"]{
  color: #707070;
}

.input-field input[type="date"]:valid{
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-field">
    <label>Iban</label>
    <input id="iban" name="iban" pattern="[A-Za-z]{24}" maxlength="24" required />
    <span class="status"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

PD: He agregado una limitación de 24 caracteres al campo del formulario para que puedas comprobar rápidamente el funcionamiento.