# Problema envio formulario javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, formularios

Estoy estudiando y llevo la parte de JavaScript de un proyecto final de estudios. He creado un archivo de validación pero no funciona como quiero.

En la última función, si añado el *listener* con el evento `submit` al elemento `formulario`, ejecuta correctamente toda la función. Me devuelve por consola que envía el formulario, pero no ingresa los datos en la tabla que corresponde.

Si añado el evento al botón `enviar`, envía el formulario, lo añade a la tabla pero se salta todo el código de la función y no muestra la confirmación.

Éste es el código:

```js
// Selector de elementos
const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario"); //form
const servicio = document.querySelector(".form-select"); //select
const enviar = document.getElementById("iniciarSesion"); //button

//Recogida
const direccionRecogida = document.getElementById("direccionRecogida");
const numeroRecogida = document.getElementById("numeroRecogida");
const pisoRecogida = document.getElementById("pisoRecogida");
const codpostalRecogida = document.getElementById("codpostalRecogida");
const ciudadRecogida = document.getElementById("ciudadRecogida");
const paisRecogida = document.getElementById("paisRecogida");

//Error select
const selectError = document.getElementById("selectError");

//Errores recogida
const direccionRecogidaError = document.getElementById(
    "direccionRecogidaError"
);
const numeroRecogidaError = document.getElementById("numeroRecogidaError");
const pisoRecogidaError = document.getElementById("pisoRecogidaError");
const codpostalRecogidaError = document.getElementById(
    "codpostalRecogidaError"
);
const ciudadRecogidaError = document.getElementById("ciudadRecogidaError");
const paisRecogidaError = document.getElementById("paisRecogidaError");

//Envio
const direccionEnvio = document.getElementById("direccionEnvio");
const numeroEnvio = document.getElementById("numeroEnvio");
const pisoEnvio = document.getElementById("pisoEnvio");
const codpostalEnvio = document.getElementById("codpostalEnvio");
const ciudadEnvio = document.getElementById("ciudadEnvio");
const paisEnvio = document.getElementById("paisEnvio");

//Envio errores
const direccionEnvioError = document.getElementById("direccionEnvioError");
const numeroEnvioError = document.getElementById("numeroEnvioError");
const pisoEnvioError = document.getElementById("pisoEnvioError");
const codpostalEnvioError = document.getElementById("codpostalEnvioError");
const ciudadEnvioError = document.getElementById("ciudadEnvioError");
const paisEnvioError = document.getElementById("paisEnvioError");

/* //Funcion validar select
function validarSelect() {
  if (!servicio.value || servicio.value === "") {
    console.log(servicio.value + "estoy en if");
    selectError.style.display = "block";
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log(servicio.value + "estoy en else");
    selectError.style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }
}

//Validacion select
servicio.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  console.log(servicio.value + "estoy en change");
  if (!servicio.value || servicio.value === "") {
    console.log(servicio.value + "estoy en if");
        selectError.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    console.log(servicio.value + "estoy en else");
        selectError.style.display = "none";
    }
}); */

//Validacion  recogida
direccionRecogida.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (
        !direccionRecogida.value ||
        !/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/.test(direccionRecogida.value)
    ) {
        direccionRecogidaError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        direccionRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (direccionRecogida.value === "") {
        direccionRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

numeroRecogida.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!numeroRecogida.value || !/^[0-9]+$/.test(numeroRecogida.value)) {
        numeroRecogidaError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        numeroRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (numeroRecogida.value === "") {
        numeroRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

pisoRecogida.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!pisoRecogida.value || !/^[0-9a-zA-Zºª/\s-]+$/.test(pisoRecogida.value)) {
        pisoRecogidaError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        pisoRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (pisoRecogida.value === "") {
        pisoRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

codpostalRecogida.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!codpostalRecogida.value || !/^[0-9]{5}$/.test(codpostalRecogida.value)) {
        codpostalRecogidaError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        codpostalRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (codpostalRecogida.value === "") {
        codpostalRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

ciudadRecogida.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (
        !ciudadRecogida.value ||
        !/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñç\s]+$/.test(ciudadRecogida.value)
    ) {
        ciudadRecogidaError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        ciudadRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (ciudadRecogida.value === "") {
        ciudadRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

paisRecogida.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!paisRecogida.value || !/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñç\s]+$/.test(paisRecogida.value)) {
        paisRecogidaError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        paisRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (paisRecogida.value === "") {
        paisRecogidaError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

//Validacion envio
direccionEnvio.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!direccionEnvio.value || !/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/.test(direccionEnvio.value)) {
        direccionEnvioError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        direccionEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (direccionEnvio.value === "") {
        direccionEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

numeroEnvio.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!numeroEnvio.value || !/^[0-9]+$/.test(numeroEnvio.value)) {
        numeroEnvioError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        numeroEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (numeroEnvio.value === "") {
        numeroEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

pisoEnvio.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!pisoEnvio.value || !/^[0-9a-zA-Zºª/\s-]+$/.test(pisoEnvio.value)) {
        pisoEnvioError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        pisoEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (pisoEnvio.value === "") {
        pisoEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

codpostalEnvio.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!codpostalEnvio.value || !/^[0-9]{5}$/.test(codpostalEnvio.value)) {
        codpostalEnvioError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        codpostalEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (codpostalEnvio.value === "") {
        codpostalEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

ciudadEnvio.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!ciudadEnvio.value || !/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñç\s]+$/.test(ciudadEnvio.value)) {
        ciudadEnvioError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        ciudadEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (ciudadEnvio.value === "") {
        ciudadEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

paisEnvio.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    if (!paisEnvio.value || !/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñç\s]+$/.test(paisEnvio.value)) {
        paisEnvioError.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        paisEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }

    if (paisEnvio.value === "") {
        paisEnvioError.style.display = "none";
    }
});

formulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var camposVacios = [];

    var formul = document.forms[0];
    var inputs = formulario.getElementsByTagName("input");

    var elementosFormulario = formul.elements;
    console.log(inputs);

    for (var i = 0; i < elementosFormulario.length; i++) {
        if (!elementosFormulario[i].value) {
            camposVacios.push(elementosFormulario[i].name);
        }
    }

    console.log(camposVacios);

    if (camposVacios.length > 0) {
        var message = "Los siguientes campos están vacíos: \n";
        for (var j = 0; j < camposVacios.length; j++) {
            message += "- " + camposVacios[j] + "\n";
    }
    message += "¿Desea enviar el formulario de todas formas?";
        if (!confirm(message)) {
            console.log("Envío del formulario cancelado por el usuario");
            return;
        }
    }

    console.log("Enviando formulario...");
  formul.submit();
  console.log("Formulario enviado");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form id="formulario" role="form" method="post" class="col-md-10" name="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <h1 class="tituloForm">Realizar un pedido</h1>
  <div class="col-12 form-floating mb-3">
    <select id="servicio" class="form-select" name="servicio" required>
      <option value="" selected>Selecciona el servicio</option>
      <option value="7">Reparación</option>
      <option value="1">Restauración</option>
      <option value="2">Limpieza</option>
      <option value="3">Enzapatillado</option>
      <option value="4">Ajuste</option>
      <option value="5">Mantenimiento Avanzado</option>
      <option value="6">Fabricación de piezas</option>
    </select>
    <label for="servicio">Servicio</label>
    <div style="color:red;display:none" id="selectError">Debe elegir un servicio</div>
  </div>
  <hr class="mt-5 mb-5">
  <p><b>Dirección de recogida del instrumento:</b></p> <!--Añadir tooltip de que solo lo tiene que rellenar si
            quiere enviar el instrumento a la tienda en lugar de llevarlo en persona-->
  <div class="col-12 form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="text" id="direccionRecogida" class="form-control" name="direccionRecogida" placeholder="Dirección">
    <label for="direccionRecogida">Dirección:</label>
    <div style="color:red;display:none" id="direccionRecogidaError">El campo solamente admite valores alfanuméricos</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="numeroRecogida" class="form-control" name="numeroRecogida" placeholder="Número">
      <label for="numeroRecogida">Número:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="numeroRecogidaError">El campo solamente admite valores numéricos</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="pisoRecogida" class="form-control" name="pisoRecogida" placeholder="Piso">
      <label for="pisoRecogida">Piso:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="pisoRecogidaError">El campo solamente admite valores alfanuméricos y los símbolos: º ª - /</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="codpostalRecogida" class="form-control" name="codpostalRecogida" placeholder="Código postal">
      <label for="codpostalRecogida">Código postal:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="codpostalRecogidaError">El CP han de ser 5 números</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="ciudadRecogida" class="form-control" name="ciudadRecogida" placeholder="Ciudad">
      <label for="paisRecogida">Ciudad:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="ciudadRecogidaError">El campo ciudad solo admite letras</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="paisRecogida" class="form-control" name="paisRecogida" placeholder="País">
      <label for="paisRecogida">País:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="paisRecogidaError">El campo pais solo admite letras</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="mt-5 mb-5">
  <p><b>Dirección de envío del instrumento:</b></p> <!--Añadir tooltip de que solo lo tiene que rellenar si
            quiere que enviemos el instrumento a su casa en lugar de recogerlo en persona-->
  <div class="col-12 form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="text" id="direccionEnvio" class="form-control" name="direccionEnvio" placeholder="Dirección">
    <label for="direccionEnvio">Dirección:</label>
    <div style="color:red;display:none" id="direccionEnvioError">El campo solamente admite valores alfanuméricos</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="numeroEnvio" class="form-control" name="numeroEnvio" placeholder="Número">
      <label for="numeroEnvio">Número:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="numeroEnvioError">El campo solamente admite valores numéricos</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="pisoEnvio" class="form-control" name="pisoEnvio" placeholder="Piso">
      <label for="pisoEnvio">Piso:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="pisoEnvioError">El campo solamente admite valores numéricos y los símbolos: º ª - /</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="codpostalEnvio" class="form-control" name="codpostalEnvio" placeholder="Código postal">
      <label for="codpostalEnvio">Código postal:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="codpostalEnvioError">El CP han de ser 5 números</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="ciudadEnvio" class="form-control" name="ciudadEnvio" placeholder="Ciudad">
      <label for="ciudadEnvio">Ciudad:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="ciudadEnvioError">El campo ciudad solo admite letras</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="paisEnvio" class="form-control" name="paisEnvio" placeholder="País">
      <label for="paisEnvio">País:</label>
      <div style="color:red;display:none" id="paisEnvioError">El campo pais solo admite letras</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="mt-5 mb-5">
  <p><b>Aquí puedes adjuntar una imagen del instrumento si es necesario:</b></p>
  <div class="col-12 input-group mb-5">
    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" name="imagen" size="20">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
    <a href="mailto:garciamusic@gmail.com">¿Necesitas ayuda? ¡Contacta con nosotros!</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap">
    <button type="submit" id="iniciarSesion" class="btn btn-secondary" name="crearPedido" value="crear pedido">Realizar pedido</button>
  </div>
  <div id="msgError" style="margin-top: 10px; color:red;font-weight:bold; text-align:center"></div>
</form>
```

El script valida los campos del formulario en vivo según el usuario interactúa con ellos, y por último, tengo la función con un listener asociado al evento `submit`.

No entiendo el error, llevo varios días atascado y no consigo dar con ello.

Reescribo de nuevo solamente la función por si es más cómodo de visualizar:

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var camposVacios = [];

    var formul = document.forms[0];
    var inputs = formulario.getElementsByTagName("input");

    var elementosFormulario = formul.elements;
    console.log(inputs);

    for (var i = 0; i < elementosFormulario.length; i++) {
        if (!elementosFormulario[i].value) {
            camposVacios.push(elementosFormulario[i].name);
        }
    }

    console.log(camposVacios);

    if (camposVacios.length > 0) {
        var message = "Los siguientes campos están vacíos: \n";
        for (var j = 0; j < camposVacios.length; j++) {
            message += "- " + camposVacios[j] + "\n";
    }
    message += "¿Desea enviar el formulario de todas formas?";
        if (!confirm(message)) {
            console.log("Envío del formulario cancelado por el usuario");
            return;
        }
    }

    console.log("Enviando formulario...");
  formul.submit();
  console.log("Formulario enviado");
});
```

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

NOTA: sé que existe la biblioteca `validate` para jQuery, pero quiero hacer el proyecto en JavaScript sin complementos. Quizá sean ganas de complicarme la vida, pero quiero intentar aprender JavaScript sin bibliotecas externas ni marcos de trabajo.

Comment: Pues no se, pero yo lo he probado y funciona perfectamente. Asegúrate de que te carga el archivo con los scripts o si los tienes en la página, que la etiqueta script vaya justo antes de que se cierre el body

Comment: Primer consejo: ahórrate todos los `const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario")`. Recuerda que JavaScript crea una propiedad en `window` (el ámbito global por defecto) con la `id` de cada elemento del DOM que tenga el atributo `id` definido. De modo que `formulario` ya existía antes de que lo declararas.

Comment: Segundo consejo: no necesitas JavaScript para comprobar el contenido de un campo mediante expresiones regulares. Basta con usar el atributo [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) y el selector CSS [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) y e `:invalid`(mira [este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/581862/18608) que puse hace pocos días).

Comment: Tercer consejo, cuidado con las comprobaciones con conversión de tipos como `if (!elementosFormulario[i].value)`. Además, esa comprobación se hace innecesaria si haces uso del atributo [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required). Aunque veo que luego pides confirmación para enviarlo aunque estén vacíos, en ese caso puedes mantener la comprobación, pero solo de los campos necesarios mediante una búsqueda `querySelectorAll()` a través de un atributo inventado o `data-*` que lo marque como opcional con confirmación.

Comment: Cuarto consejo: usa `e.preventDefault()` solo para evitar el envío del formulario si deseas cancelar el envío. Tú lo estás usando inmediatamente por defecto y luego tratas de enviar el formulario usando el método `submit()`. Deja que el flujo natural delas cosas fluya hasta que necesites detenerlo.

Comment: Te digo lo mismo que @Suso, también me funciona el envío. He editado tu pregunta para que se pueda probar tu código dentro de la pregunta. Podrás comprobar en el inspector de red del navegador que los datos del formulario se envían correctamente codificados como `Content-Disposition: form-data` (se envía la cabecera `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` debido a que así lo indicaste en el `<form enctype>`). Entonces.. ¿tienes una versión en línea para que podamos probar si el problema es algo que no se puede reproducir solo con el código que has compartido?

Comment: Hola, en cuanto pueda probaré todo lo comentado por @OscarGarcia. En cuanto a la version en linea aún no hemos subido nada al servidor, pero estamos mirando de hacerlo. Muchas gracias por el tiempo tomado en contestar, a ver si consigo dar con el motivo y a la que podamos, lo subiré también

Comment: No entiendo bien el segundo comentario, el primero de @OscarGarcia. hay alguna otra forma de definir un elemento del DOM que no sea con getElement o selectQuery?  Creía que era imprescindible para poder trabajar con ellos utilizando un nombre de variable/constante

Comment: Y una última cosa, que veo al menos curiosa: si en la ultima función uso el formulario como escuchador del evento

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
```
refresca la página, entiendo que envía el formulario porque el mensaje en consola es muy rápido, pero no lo inserta en la tabla de pedidos

En cambio, si pongo el botón a la escucha, si que inserta el pedido en la tabla, pero no salta el confirm, es como si se pasara el código de la función por alto`

```
enviar.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
```

Comment: [Creo que el tema se extiende demasiado en los comentarios. Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142756/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-rastajuan).